# Dropbox JS mass writeFile not writing all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have this code that is supposed to run through file in every subdirectory of a certain directory, make the same directory (with the same path) in my Dropbox, and upload the file to that directory in my Dropbox. I am using the [node-walk](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk) plugin.

```
//This runs for every file
walker.on('file', function(path, stats, next){
    //Path to where it should upload to on my Dropbox
    var uploadPath = (dbPath + datePath + (path + '/uOcME0OGzMf7G3h39INs' + stats.name).replace('tmp-62u3dPAStPa6upQUa4G4/', '')).split('uOcME0OGzMf7G3h39INs');

    //Path to the file that it's scanning
    var localPath = path + '/' + stats.name;

                //The path without file
    client.mkdir(uploadPath[0], function(error){
        if (error) { return error; }

        fs.readFile(localPath, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                logToFile('fs.readFile error: ' + error);
                console.error(error);
            }

            client.writeFile(uploadPath.join(''), data, function(error, stat){
                if (error) {
                    logToFile('writeFile error: ' + error);
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    next();
});
```

The problem is that in order to upload the files, I have to run the script many times (30+ times) in order for most of the files to upload. But even then there are some files that do not upload.

This is the error I get. Sometimes when I run the script there are no errors, but the next time there are. All of the files are never there, even if there is no error. I would like to prevent this from coming up if possible.

`Dropbox API error 503 from POST https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/dropbox/path/for/file/here.css :: {"error": "Failed to grab locks for 871742009, please re-issue request."}`

What can I do differently so all of the files upload in one go?

Comment: Could you please share the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because you're kicking off a lot of parallel uploads. Some are succeeding because they're queued up and blocked on the server, but if you send more than a few concurrent requests, it's quite likely that some will time out while waiting their turn.

You'll need to do your uploads sequentially, one at a time (or at least a small number at a time) to avoid this type of error.

**EDIT**: The code you want is probably something like this. (I haven't tested it at all.) I took out the call to `mkdir`, since directories are created implicitly in Dropbox, but the important change is the placement of the call to `next()`. (I'm assuming things about how `walker` works, but I don't know how it behaves. If this still doesn't work, you may want to log something when you call `writeFile` to see when it's getting called.)

```
//This runs for every file
walker.on('file', function (path, stats, next) {
    //Path to where it should upload to on my Dropbox
    var uploadPath = (dbPath + datePath + (path + '/uOcME0OGzMf7G3h39INs' + stats.name).replace('tmp-62u3dPAStPa6upQUa4G4/', ''));

    //Path to the file that it's scanning
    var localPath = path + '/' + stats.name;

    fs.readFile(localPath, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            logToFile('fs.readFile error: ' + error);
            console.error(error);
        }

        client.writeFile(uploadPath, data, function (error, stat) {
            if (error) {
                logToFile('writeFile error: ' + error);
                console.error(error);
            }
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried using setTimeout() to pause the script for 15 seconds after 1 time through, but it didn't work. I saw 10+ 503 errors in less than 5 seconds. [Am I doing something wrong here?](http://pastebin.com/fLs4VHf2)

Comment: @Bramt you should call `next()` in the callback from `writeFile()`; that way, it will wait until the file has been written to Dropbox before commencing with the next file. Although you need to clean up the error handling a bit as well.